# Ajax wont stop if false

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have problem with my ajax,

here my index:

```
<form name="add_name" id="add_name">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-row mb-2">
      ID Kurir :
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="idkurir" name="idkurir" placeholder="Input ID Kurir" class="idkurir" autofocus />
      </div>
      Nama Kurir :
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="namakurir" name="namakurir" value="Nama Kurir" class="namakurir" readonly />
      </div>
      No Laporan :
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" id="nolaporan" name="nolaporan" value="No Laporan" readonly />
      </div>
      Date :
      <div class="col">
        <?php $now=date('d-m-Y H:i'); ?>
        <input type="text" name="date" value=<?php echo "'$now'"; ?> readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field1">
          <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align=center><strong>Antar Ulang</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="awbau[]" placeholder="Enter AWB" class="form-control name_listau" /></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="addau" id="addau" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field2">
          <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align=center><strong>Undelivery</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="awbundel[]" placeholder="Enter AWB" class="form-control name_listundel" /></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="addundel" id="addundel" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <center><input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block mb-4 mr-2" value="Submit Data" /></center>
</form>
```

here my ajax script :

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".idkurir", function(e) {
  var idkurir = $('#idkurir').val();
  if (e.which == 13) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "checkdata.php",
      data: {
        idkurir: idkurir
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == 1) {
          alert("Kurir sudah laporan");
        } else {
          if (response == "ID Kurir tidak di temukan") {
            alert(response);
          } else {
            var d = new Date();
            var today_date = ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            $('#nolaporan').val(idkurir + today_date);
            $('#namakurir').val(response);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

and here my checkdata to check if data exist :

```
session_start();
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("reportchecker", $connect);
$idkurir = $_POST["idkurir"];
$nolaporan = $idkurir . date("dm");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jampulang WHERE nolaporan = '$nolaporan'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$response = [];
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM kurir WHERE idkurir = '$idkurir'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);
if ($count == 1) {
    echo "1";
} else if ($count2 == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result2) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $row['nama'];
} else {
    echo "ID Kurir tidak di temukan";
}
```

my problem is when response from checkdata = "ID Kurir tidak di temukan", ajax not showing alert and stop update field nolaporan and nama kurir

```
$('#nolaporan').val(idkurir + today_date);
$('#namakurir').val(response);
```

in my script above when reponse "ID Kurir tidak di temukan" still update field nolaporan and namakurir.

Comment: Oh no! You are wide open to SQL Injection attacks! What if $nolaporan is `'; DROP TABLE jampulang; --`?

Comment: i use this only for offline data

Comment: the mysql extension has been obsolete for years, and has been completely removed in PHP 7.x. You should convert to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Try putting `response = response.trim()` at the beginning of the `success` function. There may be extra whitespace around the response.

Comment: Put `console.log(response)` to see exactly what the response is.

Comment: oke i got the point,, i changed if condition and solved

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it on the client side using `$.trim()` like below:

```
if($.trim(response) == 'ID Kurir tidak di temukan') {
        //do your code
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).